# Error in Publishing .Net Core Web App on Docker Hub

Tags: azure, docker, asp.net-core, dockerhub

I am learning docker and containers. I am trying to Publish my .Net Core 3.1 Web App on Docker Hub via visual studio 2019. I am on Windows PC, But the visual studio deployment environment is set to Linux and Docker also set to Linux. I have installed WSL2 (Windows subsystem for linux 2) as well. Also the Web app is executing well and at the same time I can see the container and image is created into Docker dashboard (running) successfully. However, while trying to publish it on Docker Hub, I am getting below error.

Can you help me out that which part is missing on my PC (it is azure windows 10 VM)?

**Note:** I am able to run linux containers as well without any issue. Also Ubuntu 20 is installed from Windows Shop.

```
2021-07-01 10:19:58 AM
Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.Publish.Docker.DockerCommandException: Running the docker.exe tag command failed.

Current context "desktop-linux" is not found on the file system, please check your config file at C:\Users\kulkarnis009\AppData\Local\Temp\7961a412d485473395194d8ad39fe785\config.json
   at Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.Publish.Docker.DockerOperations.ThrowDockerCommandError(String dockerCommand)
   at Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.Publish.Docker.DockerOperations.<DockerTagAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.Publish.Docker.DockerPublish.<DockerPublishAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.Publish.ContainerRegistry.ManageContainerRegistry.<PushImageAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.Publish.PublishProviders.ContainerRegistryProfileVisual.<PostPublishAsync>d__38.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Nexus.PublishProfilesServiceImpl.ServerProjectProfilesManager.<RunPublishTaskAsync>d__53.MoveNext()

===================
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

in the file

```
file:///C:/Users/UserName/AppData/Local/Temp/c69e796a148440f18675b80111e06796/config.json
```

Change desktop-linux

```
{
  "auths": {},
  "credsStore": "desktop",
  "currentContext": "default",
  "stackOrchestrator": "swarm",
  "HttpHeaders": {
    "X-Meta-Source-Client": "vs/web/publish"
  }
}
```

currentContext had desktop-linux, I just put "default"

Comment: Worked for me too. But how long does an edit of a file in "temp" last? Maybe the files in c:\Users\<user>\.docker should be edited...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and I was was able to resolve by switching the docker context back to default (it was set to desktop-linux) using the command:

```
docker context use default
```

Comment: Hi Chris. Thank you for your inputs. However, I have tried this command executing in command prompt and tried publishing app again into Docker hub. But no luck. Are there any other steps that I need to follow along with it. Also note that, My docker is set to Linux environment and installed WSL2 as well. I want the underline environment as LInux only. I think I am missing some configurations on my VM. let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Reverting to Docker for Windows 3.4.0 worked for me.

Download it here:
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/#docker-desktop-340

This bug is discussed here:
https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/11530
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/unable-to-publish-to-acr-running-the-dockerexe-tag/1464650
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/current-context-desktop-linux-is-not-found-on-the/1463380